# Wireless networked device not receiving packets

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, arp

I'm using [create_ap](http://github.com/oblique/create_ap) (based on hostapd) to use an old desktop Linux computer as a wireless router. This works fine for my Android smartphone, but not for my two Linux laptops. The connection will stop working after a minute or two - I'm suddenly unable to ping the gateway.

I fired up Wireshark on both the old desktop and one of my laptops. When the network stops working, the laptop starts sending ARP requests (who-has 192.168.0.1, tell 192.168.0.103). These appear on both the laptop and old desktop's Wireshark logs. The desktop will reply to these ARP requests giving its mac address, and these replies appear on the desktop's Wireshark logs. However, these replies do not appear in the laptop's Wireshark logs. Because the laptop isn't receiving a response to these queries, it lists the gateway as incomplete in its ARP table, making it unable to send any network traffic. This leads me to believe that the issue is caused by the laptop not receiving any packets during these sporadic intervals.

I've tried disabling power saving mode on the access point, which did not affect this behavior. I've also tried multiple OSes (Debian, Parrot Security, Ubuntu) and multiple network managers (NetworkManager and Wicd).

At the moment, I've just been disconnecting and reconnecting the laptops, which temporarily solves the problem.

Comment: Is this a sort-of experiment or are you actually trying to use an **old desktop** computer with a guessed power consumption of 200-400W as a wireless router? Is there any reason for that? This sounds really pricey. As for your question: Is your wireless card supported? Not all wifi cards support AP mode on the hardware side.

Comment: I've confirmed that my chipset (rt2561)  supports AP mode. As for power consumption, this is in a dorm room, so I'm not the one paying for the electricity . It's also a temporary setup; it just has to last me a month or so at most.

Comment: It's weird how it works but just for a minute or two. I don't know much about this kinda stuff, but are you using DHCP? Maybe disabling that and manually setting the IP addresses helps.

Comment: I am using DHCP, thanks for the advice. I probably won't be able to test it right away, but once I try using static IPs I'll post my findings.

Comment: `create_ap` just seems to be a shell script to call `hostapd`. So the obvious thing to do is to enable more verbose logging in `hostapd`, and see if anything pops up.ARP requests are a symptom, not related to the cause. `iw`, `hostapd_cli` and `wpa_cli` to examine the current status of the connection and attempt reconnect should also be helpful.